# MongoDB: How to determine the compressed data size in Wired Tiger?

Tags: mongodb

Are there some stats or values that can be queried from Mongo with WiredTiger to determine the remaining storage space in Mongo before the compressed data space will force it to grow?  With WiredTiger compression, the data space reports only uncompressed sizes.

Answer (score 0):

Bit of an old question, but if anyone else is looking you can use db.getCollection('colName').storageSize();

Documented here: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.storageSize/

Comment: Wouldn't storage size include free space where as data size does not?